# Boolos’s proof of the first incompleteness theorem. Predicate $C(x,y)$ and assumption of completeness.

Tags: logic, computability, incompleteness, decidability

I am trying really hard to understand how Boolos’s proof works, but I keep having doubts about it. Can you spot any logical flaws in my reasoning? This question arose from a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3868997/boolos-s-proof-of-g%c3%b6del-s-first-incompleteness-theorem-what-am-i-getting-wrong), but it is different from it as a consequence of things that were explained to me in response to such previous question.

The first incompleteness theorem states that any consistent theory is not complete. In other words, stated very naively, the result of the proof is: ¬(“true” ↔ “provable”). To avoid making a circular argument, the assumption about the theory that carries out our proof must be “true” ↔ “provable”. If our theory starts with this assumption, it seems to me that it can be showed $C(x,y) → ¬C(x,y)$ and therefore $¬C(x,y)$ can be proved by contradiction (with $C(x,y)$ being the predicate found in Boolos's proof). The reason for this is it seems to me that assuming $C(x,y)$ true allows you to prove both $∃n(∀(()↔=[]))$ and $¬∃n(∀(()↔=[]))$.

$∃n(∀(()↔=[]))$ has to be proved as part of Boolos’s proof (it is asserted to be true along the proof). From the assumption “true” ↔ “provable”, ¬∃n(∀(()↔=[])) can be deduced in a few mechanical steps. If the implication $(∀(()↔=[]) → ¬∀(()↔=[]))$ is true then we also have $¬∃n(∀(()↔=[]))$. It can be seen easily by rewriting $∀(()↔=[])$ as $J(n)$ and using proof by contradiction $(J(n) → ¬J(n)) → ¬J(n)$ and the generalisation inference rule $J(n) → ∀nJ(n)$. Then just substitute $¬∃n¬$ with $∀n$ (they are syntactically the same) to get $∀n¬J(n) ↔ ¬∃n¬¬J(n) ↔ ¬∃nJ(n) ↔ ¬∃n(∀(()↔=[n]))$.

Now, how can we show the implication $(∀(()↔=[]) → ¬∀(()↔=[]))$ to be true? We see that $∀(()↔=[])$ implies $A(n,m)$. Let’s say $F(x)$ is d symbols long, with d<m by construction ($m = 10k$ and $d = 2k + 24$ in Boolos’s proof).
We also have $A(n,m) → ¬(C(n,y) ∧ (y<m)) → ¬C(n,d) → ¬∀(()↔=[n])$.

An objection could be: $¬C(n,d)$ just implies that there is no proof for $∀(()↔=[n])$, it does not imply $¬∀(()↔=[n])$. But if we have to start with the assumption “true” ↔ “provable” we can deduce these two things are exactly the same.

So to summarise, it seems to me that starting by the assumption that your theory is consistent and complete, $¬C(x,y)$ is proved by showing $C(x,y)$ leads to contradiction. Therefore to me it looks like Boolos’s proof cannot be carried out if you start from these assumptions. But these are the assumptions you have to start from to avoid making a circular argument.

Comment: Is $C(x,y)$ a formula whatever (with two free vars), or is it the formula defined by Boolos at page 385: "let $C(x,z)$ a formula of the language of arithmetic that says that $x$ is the number that is named by some formula containing $z$ symbols" ?

Comment: (,) is the predicate you find in Boolos's proof, I'll modify the question to specify it, thank you.

Comment: It is not clear to me your reading of formula $C$: "$C(n,d)$ just says that there is no proof for...". This is not the correct reading; see the original def (quoted in my comment above). We have (see top page 385) the formula $x+x=ssss0$ that names number *two*. It has *nine* symbols; thus, according to the def of $C$ we have that $C(2,9)$ holds.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot a negation sign, thank you again for pointing out, I already corrected it.

Comment: Nothing changes in my comment... That is not the "meaning" of $C$.

Comment: In my understanding (,) is true if and only if there is a formula of d symbols that names n. From this follows that ¬(,) is true if and only if there is no formula of d symbols that names n. Isn't it so?

Comment: I changed the word "say" with "imply" in that part of my question. Maybe I didn't explain myself very clearly...

Comment: Ok. You have written: "it seems to me that it can be showed $C(x,y) → ¬C(x,y)$." Why ? According to Boolos' example we have that $C(2,9)$ holds. Thus $\lnot C(2,9)$ is false, and thus the conditional $C(2,9) → ¬C(2,9)$ must be false.

Comment: As I wrote "The reason for this is it seems to me that assuming (,) true allows you to prove both ∃(∀(()↔=[])) and ¬∃(∀(()↔=[]))", so everything follows from that, even ¬(,). I was just trying to write concisely that it seems to me that $C(x,y)$ leads to contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the issue is with your use of formula $F(x)$.

According to Boolos' definition,

> "a formula $F(x)$ *names* a number $n$ if the statement $\forall x (F(x) \leftrightarrow x=[n])$ (where $[n]$ is $ss \ldots s0$, with $n$ times $s$) is in the output of algorithm $M$."

Boolos says (page 386): "$n$ is not named by $F$; in other words, $\forall x (F(x) \leftrightarrow x=[n])$ is not in the output of $M$."

You are switching from "$\forall x (F(x) \leftrightarrow x=[n])$ is not in the output of $M$" to "$\lnot \forall x (F(x) \leftrightarrow x=[n])$ is in the output of $M$."

But this is what we are trying to prove: that the system is [(negation) complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)#Syntactical_completeness):

> for each sentence (closed formula) $\phi$ of the language of the system either $\phi$ or $¬ \phi$ is a theorem (an output) of the system.

Thus, if $\phi$ is not an output of the system, then $\lnot \phi$ must be.

But this is exactly what $\mathsf {PA}$ is not: it is (negation) *incomplete*.

See page 383:

> a new proof of the Gödel incompleteness theorem in the form: *There is no algorithm whose output contains all true statements of arithmetic and no false ones*.

And page 384:

> if there were an algorithm that printed out **all and only** [*emphasis added*] the true statements of arithmetic...

This is the crux of the matter: from the fact that $\forall x (F(x) \leftrightarrow x=[n])$ is not in the output of $M$ we cannot conclude that $\lnot \forall x (F(x) \leftrightarrow x=[n])$ is the output of $M$.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying ¬∀(()↔=[]) is not in the output of $M$? Why?

Comment: What I am saying is: Boolos asserts at p.386 that ∀(()↔=[]) is a true statement. How do you back this assertion? I imagine you need a consistent theory that proves at least ∃(∀(()↔=[])), but it seems to me that from C(x,y) follows that any theory proving so is inconsistent.

Comment: Furthermore, you wrote "from the fact that ∀(()↔=[]) is not in the output of  we cannot conclude that ¬∀(()↔=[]) is the output of ". But I would say you could prove it by contradiction, as I did in my question. This could happen even inside $M$ and would be a viable way of producing ¬∀(()↔=[]). Do you think this would not work? Why?